# App Script to Move data daily to a new sheet, Keeping track of each days data

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking for a script that will move data from one sheet to another, moving down the columns for each day.
Day 1 copy data in B3:B24 to log sheet column A with date copied in row 1
Day 2 copy data in B3:B24 to log sheet Column B and with date copied in row 1

This is for google sheets

Answer (score 0):

#### Log Data

```
function logdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter your Sheet Name");
  const vs = sh.getRange("B3:B24").getDisplayValues();
  const lsh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter Log Sheet Name");
  const dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy")
  vs.unshift([dts]);
  lsh.getRange(1,getRowWidth(1,lsh,ss) + 1, vs.length, vs[0].length);
}

function dailyTimer() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "logdata").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("logdata").timeBased().atHour(1).everyDays(1).create();//You can add more detail if you wish
  }
}

function getRowWidth(row, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = row || sh.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var rcA = [];
  if(sh.getLastColumn()){rcA = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().reverse();}
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```